# Backbone.sync to overwrite dataType

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am building an application that uses a .CSV file as the data source for a Backbone Model. What would be the best approach to overwriting sync to use dataType "text" rather than "json"? Looking for best practice etc...

Unfortunately the "dataType" parameter used by Backbone.sync is hardcoded... and does not respond to options.dataType. The piece of code in question can be seen in the annotated source - http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-166

This is the sync method I have created on my Model. Most of which is copy paste directly from Backbone.sync. My model is also read-only.

```
sync: function(method, model, options){

    //overwrite sync to read a .CSV document. if
    //the default Backbone sync would let you
    //specify the "dataType" property, this wouldn't
    //be necessary.

    if(method === 'read'){

        options || (options = {});

        var success = options.success;
        options.success = function(resp, status, xhr) {
            if (success) success(json, status, xhr);
        };

        var params = {type: 'GET', dataType: 'text', url: this.url};
        return $.ajax(_.extend(params, options));
    }
},
```

I have overwritten "parse" to handle the CSV response.

```
parse: function(data, xhr){
    return $jQuery.parseJSON( CSVParser.toJSON(data) );
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of changing in the core of backbone, or copying the whole sync method just to change the dataType, you can use one of jQuery's not so well known functions called [ajaxPrefilter](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxPrefilter/).

Witch allows you to change the ajax request just before making it. Pretty need function.

```
jQuery.ajaxPrefilter(function( options ) {
    options.dataType = "mynewdatatype";
});
```

---

Im not sure if this works using zepto.js.